# C# Find and replace a price in a long string

Tags: c#, regex, replace, numbers, digits

I have a long string representing a web page in html, I have to change the price of a product detail, the string to be replaced would be like this: `10.20 €` or `100.22 €` or `1.50 €` etc.
the price may vary so the replace must work with any amount. 
How can I find and replace this price?
The only code I found is this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9].[0-9][0-9]", "");
```

but it is not based on the € symbol and therefore could find other similar numbers in the string and replace them and especially if in case there is a number with more digits it does not replace all the digits
thanks you

Solution by @Kenny:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]*.[0-9]* €", "");
```

thanks

Comment: You should post a sample of the line to make sure any code provided is tested.

Comment: Would the currency symbol (Euro, in your examples) always appear after the float, or could it also appear before (e.g. US dollar amounts) ?

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ever after the float and ever only €

Comment: @jdweng The string is an entire html page, it's too long I can not post it.

Comment: The really should be done in the webpage to automatically add the amount based on the culture.  See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: @Fergoluz: without us being able to see the relevant input - it is very difficult to help - it is possible to encode the Euro symbol in several ways to display correctly in HTML - https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes/html-code-euro.html

Comment: var output = Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]*.[0-9]* €", "");

Comment: @kenny thanks work :)

Comment: @Fergoluz: I would carefully check that regex - the * means match 0 or more occurrences, & the . means match any character - so the full regex will match "0 or more digits followed by any character followed by 0 or more digits followed by space and then the euro symbol" - so this may not match exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deadset on using a REGEX, all you would have to do is add a positive lookahead to your existing regex. It would look like this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9](?=\s€)", "");
```

As you can see, the `(?=\s€)` Checks to make sure that a euro symbol is present. 
To experiment more with regexes, you can use this website: [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)

The above answer also is dependant on how your HTML euro characters are encoded. You should check we're matching the right one!

Comment: That assumes the input string contains the "€" character - as it is HTML the character could be encoded in multiple ways - https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes/html-code-euro.html

Comment: This code works only if I have a price like this: 5.32 €
if you have a price like this, 55.32 €  does not replace the first digit.

Comment: You are 100% correct PaulF, I'm assuming the OP has a cosistent set of html pages and he'll be able to see how it's encoded!

Comment: Also note that this matches 0 or more digits followed by any character rather than multiple digits followed by decimal point - it should probably be "[0-9]+\\.[0-9][0-9](?=\s€)"

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s*€", "");
```

**Details**

- `[0-9]+` - 1+digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - an optional substring matching

  - `\.` - a dot (it must be escaped to match a literal dot)
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `€` - an euro sign.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%5Cs*%E2%82%AC&i=5.32%20%E2%82%AC%2055.32%20%E2%82%AC).